# Test for Difference from Mean for Each Individual Case/Value

Tags: mean, outliers, similarities, census

**I've edited this question based on feedback in the comments:**

I have a census data sample (about 9000 values) consisting of total responses and % hispanic responses in a set of zip codes, so my data looks like this:

| zip | totalresponses | hispanicresponses |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01331 | 649 | 211 |
| 18774 | 34444 | 523 |
| 93571 | 3007 | 1455 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Once I have the mean calculated for the full dataset in R, I would like to have a good measure of how significant each's zip's % hispanic difference from that mean is, as well as a good way to remove case/row outliers (for example, zip codes with extremely small populations) which might skew the results. What test would be appropriate for these requirements/type of data?

Comment: There is no such test: you need the numerators and denominators (both counts) used to compute those percentages.

Comment: I see, thank you - is there any appropriate way to compare how different the percentage for one zip is from the average of all in the dataset?

Comment: Yes -- but again provided you have the numerator and denominator counts for the percentage in that one zip (assuming the counts for the entire dataset are large, so that how large they actually are doesn't matter, and assuming that that one zip doesn't comprise a material portion of the dataset).

Comment: I actually do have the numerator/denominator data (this is American Community Survey data).

Comment: That's not quite the same, because the numerators and denominators are *estimates* from the survey.  It would be a mistake to treat them as if they were actual counts. However, the Census makes margins of error (MoE) available with the data and provides instructions and guidance on how to use them for doing analyses like yours.  Check out the technical documentation available on the ACS website.

Comment: Ah, looks like a z-test may be appropriate, I'll work on researching that and may post a separate follow up question

Comment: For a single Zip comparison, that ought to work.  But with so many Zip codes you need to adjust for multiple comparisons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123556/discussion-between-marcatectura-and-whuber).